# problem in applying custom background to layout with radius in corners

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I want to make a design like that [image]

the delivery msg is a texview with custom background and it works fine but in the bottom of it there is a constraint-layout and when I used the custom background I made for it it didn't look fine there is a shadow in the corner, this custom background was applied fine before to a button but when I use it to constraint-layout it didn't works as expect

[image]

here is the custom drawable xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/turquoise" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="14dp"
            android:topRightRadius="14dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="5dp"
            android:top="5dp"
            android:right="5dp"
            android:bottom="5dp"    >
        </padding>
        <solid android:color="@color/white"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            />
        <size android:height="60dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

how can I apply that to constraint-layout

Comment: Please attach your layout file too.

Comment: Set `app:elevation="0dp"` to views to hide shadow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is two solutions:

**Solution 1:** 
apply corners and padding to the rectangle with color `turquoise`

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/turquoise" />
            <padding android:top="28dp" />
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="14dp"
                android:topRightRadius="14dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="14dp"
                android:topRightRadius="14dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="5dp"
                android:left="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:top="5dp" />
            <solid
                android:color="@color/white"
                android:elevation="0dp" />
            <size android:height="60dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

please note that `android:top` value u have to set depending on your needs.

**Solution 2:**

create two separated layouts with the same designs just differ in layout.
set one with `turquoise` to `constraintLayout` and crate `ImageView` to have the one with white and set marginTop depending on your needs

any questions are welcomed